# Excel VBA Combo Box Macro for Changing List Items

Tags: excel, vba, filter, combobox, macros

I created an IntervieweeName named list on sheet "Tables":
[IntervieweeName named list on Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p3Xe.png)

On sheet "Assessment", I've created a combobox with a ListFillRange of IntervieweeName. The purpose of the combobox is for the worksheet to autofilter based on the criteria if "Yes" exists in the column that corresponds to the selected IntervieweeName list item.  Here is relevant data from sheet "Assessment":
[Yes/No columns for Sheet "Assessment"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVrts.png)

In order to accomplish the filter, I created this macro and it works correctly.

```
Private Sub cboIntervieweeName_Change()
    Dim IntervieweeName As String

    IntervieweeName = Me.cboIntervieweeName

    If IntervieweeName = "None" Then
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
    If IntervieweeName = "Chuck Fox" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B6:BL119").AutoFilter _
            field:=17, _
            Criteria1:="Yes", _
            VisibleDropDown:=True
    End If
     If IntervieweeName = "Rob Copeland 1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B6:BL119").AutoFilter _
            field:=19, _
            Criteria1:="Yes", _
            VisibleDropDown:=True
    End If
     If IntervieweeName = "Rob Copeland 2" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B6:BL119").AutoFilter _
            field:=21, _
            Criteria1:="Yes", _
            VisibleDropDown:=True
    End If   
  If IntervieweeName = "Rob Copeland 3" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B6:BL119").AutoFilter _
            field:=23, _
            Criteria1:="Yes", _
            VisibleDropDown:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

I also created a button macro to reset the combobox list item to 0, which is none.

```
Private Sub resetIntervieweeName_Click()
    cboIntervieweeName.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

This is great for one instance but my team would like to use this for future projects.  How do I modify the sheet(s) and/or macro to accomodate changing the names in the IntervieweeName list without having to modify the macro?

This is my first macro.  Total noob.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provide any relations of fields-columns, there isn't much generic code possible.

Your current code can be simplified to below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboIntervieweeName_Change()
    Dim lField As Long
    Select Case Me.cboIntervieweeName.Value
        Case "Chuck Fox":       lField = 17
        Case "Rob Copeland 1":  lField = 19
        Case "Rob Copeland 2":  lField = 21
        Case "Rob Copeland 3":  lField = 23
        Case Else
            Selection.AutoFilter
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B6:BL119").AutoFilter field:=lField, Criteria1:="Yes", VisibleDropDown:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what you could place in your UserForm code pane

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboIntervieweeName_Change()
    Dim lField As Long
    Dim dataRng As Range, IntervieweeNameRng As Range, found As Range


    With Worksheets("Assessment")
        Set dataRng = .Range("B6:BL119") '<== here set your "data" range, included first header row above the actual "data"
        Set IntervieweeNameRng = .Range("B5:BL5") '<== here set your "Assessment" sheet range where to search for combobox IntervieweeName selected
    End With

    If cboIntervieweeName.ListIndex > -1 Then

        Set found = IntervieweeNameRng.Find(What:=Me.cboIntervieweeName.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
        If found Is Nothing Then
            dataRng.AutoFilter  'clear possible previous .Autofilter
        Else
            lField = found.Column
            With dataRng
                .AutoFilter 'clear possible previous .Autofilter
                .AutoFilter field:=lField, Criteria1:="Yes", VisibleDropDown:=True
            End With
        End If
    Else
        dataRng.AutoFilter  'clear possible previous .Autofilter
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub resetIntervieweeName_Click()
    cboIntervieweeName.ListIndex = -1
End Sub
```

this way you can modify both range and values of `IntervieweeName` named range and still have `cboIntervieweeName` combobox "change" event handler filter "Assessment" sheet accordingly

I also modified your `resetIntervieweeName_Click` routine so as to "clear" the `cboIntervieweeName` combobox text setting its `.ListIndex` property to 1